# Ionic Photo Upload - File to Base64 String

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic App that is communicating with a rails API. I have users, and user have pictures. I have been able to follow [this guide](http://www.gajotres.net/accessing-image-galery-using-ionic-and-ngcordova/) about how to allow users to grab images natively from their phone images.

this allows the user to grab an image from their phone

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 $scope.getImageSaveContact = function() {
 // Image picker will load images according to these settings
  var options = {
    maximumImagesCount: 1,
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
    quality: 80
  };

  $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (results) {
    // Loop through acquired images
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      $scope.collection.selectedImage = results[i];   // We loading only one image so we can use it like this

      window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile($scope.collection.selectedImage, function(base64){  // Encode URI to Base64 needed for contacts plugin
        $scope.collection.selectedImage = base64;
      });
    }
    console.log("results");
    console.log(results);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
 };
});
```

The problem is, it is not running (or appears not to not be running) the `window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile` line that encodes a file. Right now, it is only the image file and not the Base64 encoded string.

How do I get this function to run, after I have grabbed a file from my device camera?

**i was able to figure it out, answer is below**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by piecing together a bunch of stuff, especially w/ the rails side. The idea is to click a button to get an image, pick one from your camera roll, convert that image to a base64 string, then send that image to the server.

my current stack is rails 4, ionic/angular v1. hopefully this helps someone else.

**angular controller**

```
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        callback(reader.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
  }

  $scope.grabImage = function () {
    var options = {
      maximumImagesCount: 1,
      width: 800,
      height: 800,
      quality: 80
    };

    $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (results) {
      $scope.dataImg = results;

      return toDataUrl($scope.dataImg, function(base64Img) {
        $scope.base64 = base64Img;
        $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: false});
      })
    }, function(error) {
      $scope.message = "Error: Failed to Attach Image";

      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'User Photos',
        templateUrl: 'templates/modals/success_or_error.html',
        scope: $scope
      });
    });
  }
```

**rails controller**

```
  def create
    image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(params[:image_file])
    image.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
    image.original_filename = "mu_#{@current_mobile_user.id}_#{@current_mobile_user.pictures.count}.jpg"
    image.content_type = "image/jpeg"
    @picture = @current_mobile_user.pictures.create(image: image, imageable_id: @current_mobile_user.id)

    if @picture.save
      render json: ['Picture Uploaded!'], status: :created
    else
      render json: [@picture.errors.full_messages.to_sentence], status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

from an old project https://github.com/aaronksaunders/firebaseStorageApp/blob/master/www/js/app.js#L132

```
  return $cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(path, fileName)
    .then(function (success) {
      // success - get blob data
      var imageBlob = new Blob([success], { type: "image/jpeg" });
   })
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I kept pretty much all my code the same, but replaced my `$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures`  with yours (in my edit). I added a series of alerts (to test on `ionic view`) and get an alert for the file name completing. However, it does not make it into the second `then` block. do you see any reason why that could be the case?

Comment: did you install the cordova-file plugin?

Comment: Yes, I did. [this is the one I installed](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

Answer (score 0):

add this camera plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

this returns image in base 64 by default..

```
$scope.choosePhoto = function () {
            $scope.myPopup.close();
            var options = {
                quality: 75,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                allowEdit: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 300,
                targetHeight: 300,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };
            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

            }, function (err) {
                // An error occured. Show a message to the user
            });
        }
```

more details can be found here
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/

hope this helps...